(Python) Как пропорционально уровнять числа в массиве "numpy"?
Задача обстоит такая, имеется массив 'numpy' из двух чисел: [5 10] Необходимо уравнять эти числа между собой, пропорционально сблизив.
Работать должно так: [5 10] --> [6 9] (сближение на 1 единицу каждого числа)
                     [5 10] --> [7 8] (сближение на 2 единицы каждого числа)

Схема: (первое число:5) 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> (7.5) <-- 8 <-- 9 <-- 10 (второе число:10)


То есть, массив сглаживается и разница между его значениями
понижается. На схеме показано как два числа одновременно приближаются к их "среднему арифметическому" (7.5)

Подозреваю что у 'numpy' есть некий метод, делающий это. Без необходимости строить длинный код. Подскажите братцы.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy Мне нужно не получить средне арифметическое, а сделать новый массив [6, 9] или [7, 8]. Желательно с задаваемым значением "сглаживания".

@Stanislav Volodarskiy Есть один массив с множеством чисел, нужно всего лишь уменьшить разницу между ними.

Для чего вы это делаете? Какая цель? Зачем? Какую задачу решаете?

@Stanislav Volodarskiy Есть чёрно белое изображение 10 x 10 в виде массива, на нём изображен градиент светлыми и тёмными пикселями. Нужно сделать его мутным, но не высветлить и не затемнить.

Размытие по Гауссу. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920953/14775762

Чтобы изменить контраст в c раз: c * (a - np.average(a)) + np.average(a).
